# mail.jar could not be found, Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7

Checking out a java project, I am alerted *mail.jar could not be found*.

I think this has something to do with the `javax.mail` library but I am not very familiar with  java.

Is this an standard java library?  If so, where do I find it? and how do I link it into my netbeans project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JavaMail API is packaged within `javax.mail` as you mentioned.

In response to your questions:

> Is this an standard java library?

It is optional with Java SE and is included with Java EE.  This is from [Oracle's documentation on JavaMail API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html).

> If so, where do I find it?

You can download the JavaMail API JAR from Oracle: [JavaMail API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index-138643.html)

I downloaded JavaMail 1.4.5.  It comes down as a ZIP file, and there is a `mail.jar` file contained within the `javamail1_4_5.zip` file.

The `mail.jar` contains the JavaMail API and implementation.

> and how do I link it into my netbeans project?

Since I don't have any specific information or details on your Java project, I couldn't give you any more information on which exact version of JavaMail API to download and how to integrate it into your NetBeans project.  However, you should be able to get almost any modern version of the JavaMail API from the link I provided above.

Comment: Usually, one needs also to install JAF, to use JavaMail. JavaMail itself seems to have been moved from Oracle to java.net, at least version 1.5.1.